# Basic node error: app.use() requires a middleware function

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node and am having some probably very basic trouble with an error message that I cannot fix:

```
proj/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:210
    throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')
```

I've been trying to use the csrf token module but for some reason I'm getting the above error code - literally clueless as to finding a fix here. May be very obvious to some - does anyone have any ideas?

This is the offending line of code: `app.use(csrfProtection); // ERROR HERE: REASON UNKNOWN`

I have installed the csurf module exactly identically to the tutorial I'm following. Any help would be **much** appreciated - original code is below:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // enables use of body parser - body parser helps get data entered from a form (via req.body)
const subRoutes = require('./routes/subs');
const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
const mongoConnect = require('./util/database').mongoConnect;
let mailActivator = require('./util/nodemailer'); // activates nodemailer.js
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session); // session argument from express-session
const csrf = require('csrf');

const store = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: 'mongodb+srv://_____:______@empool-3klmr.mongodb.net/______',
    collection: 'sessions'
});

const csrfProtection = csrf();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // use EJS templating engine
app.set('views', 'views'); // views located here

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
})); // parses text as URL encoded data (which is how browsers tend to send form data from regular forms set to POST) and exposes the resulting object (containing the keys and values) on req.body)
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for JSON post API requests

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
    secret: "my secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store
}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('This demo middleware will always run...');
    console.log('req.get("host")', req.get("host"));
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.isLoggedIn = req.session.isLoggedIn;
    res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
    next();
});

app.use(csrfProtection); // ERROR HERE: REASON UNKNOWN

app.use(subRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(adminRoutes);

//app.listen(3000);
mongoConnect(() => {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
});
console.log('App running successfully...');
```

Here

Comment: Aren't you supposed to `requre('csurf')` rather than `require('csrf')`? It could be a simple typo.

Comment: Isnt the package called "csurf" not "csrf"?

Comment: or maybe `const csrfProtection = new csrf();` ?

Comment: @OlivierKrull: not really, the [csurf package](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf) is well documented and the call doesn't need `new`.

Comment: thank you - csurf fixed it. Amazing how such a tiny error can break everything

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yes I was too fast during checking the `csrf` package mentioned in OP's question and he's indeed probably looking for `csurf`.